# Adding a .lib file to a project in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, static-libraries

I have generated a `.lib` file from another project that I would like to use in my project. I have added the file to *Linker* → *Input* → *Additional dependencies* as `bluetoothserialport.lib`.

I've added the lib file inside my project at this level: http://i65.tinypic.com/1t9fki.jpg

However I get the following error:

> 1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'bluetoothserialport.lib'

I am using Windows 10 and C++.

Comment: Try adding the path to the library in Additional Library Directories.

Comment: You'd think this question would have a better answer by now. Or at least the top answer would be upvoted more so we could know if it is correct

Answer (score 4):

If you come from an Xcode background you might expect a reasonable IDE to know what all the things in a project are. Visual Studio is not such an IDE.

You need to, explicitly, go to the *Linker* → *General* → *Additional Library Directories*, and add a path to your .lib there.

Comment: I'm also an Xcode user and find myself in the same situation as the op, but to be fair: there are also settings to be made in Xcode. And if you've ever compiled a dylib, you will know that this is also not very straight forward.